# python 2.7 Dictionary passing argument to .get

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I've created a number of functions to help me run my current program. Where possible I'm trying to utilise these custom elements, as many times as possible, just to keep their number fairly reasonable.

**To the point.**

I've wrote below to allow me to search through various dictionaries where result is in the form of list i.e. People = {'IR1': [65, 'M', 77076], 'IR2': [24, 'M', 77077], ....}
IR = unique person identifier
1st position in the list - AGE,
2nd position in the list - Gender,
3rd position in the list - GP practice code.

To pick up each necessary value I'm using:

```
def TestCustom1(Search, Source, Offset):

    if Search == 'Blank' or Search == 'Missing IRF - MT' or \
    Search == 'Missing IRF - source data' or Search is None or \
    Search == 'Date out of scope':
        CusRet = 'Blank'

    elif Source.get(Search) is not None:
        CusRet = TestType('CharZ', Source.get(Search)[Offset])

    else:
        CusRet = 'Missing from look up tbl'

    return CusRet
```

Where:
TestType, evaluates the results (i.e. if value is Null it will return 'Blank').
Search = look up value, Source = name of the Dictionary, Offset = value position.
I'm using this to support around 5 different dictionaries.

**Problem:**
I've got very simple Dictionary = {'AA20':'Intradural Spine Major 1', .....}

When using the following in the editor everything works correctly:

```
DictHRG.get('HC08Z')[0:]
u'Intradural Spine Major 1'
```

But when trying to pass [0:] into the function I've made, there is en error:

```
TestCustom1('HC08Z', DictHRG, 0:)
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

and

```
TestCustom1('HC08Z', DictHRG, [0:])
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**Sollution:**
1. I could write a new function, but as mentioned I'm trying to keep a reasonable number of them
2. I could use IF statement in the code for this particular dataset, but would prefer to use the TestCustom1 (as on blanks I need the same output for all the datasources):

```
CusRet = 'Missing from look up tbl'
```

and it's easier to change it in the function if needed rather the going back to this one set (I've got over 50 datasources)

**Question:**
Can you possibly adice on above, also suggestion on alternatives would be greatly appreciated (I'm pretty sure It is some rookie mistake I'm making).

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You should name your variables in lowercase, as uppercase reflect class names. See http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions

Comment: Seen that but it's a bad habbit I've got from MS Excel VBA. Once I'm not a python rookie I might start working on it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the offset in a slice:

```
CusRet = TestType('CharZ', Source.get(Search)[Offset:])
```

or pass in a [`slice()` object](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#index-68) for the offset:

```
TestCustom1('HC08Z', DictHRG, slice(0))
```

Note that `0` is the *default* starting point for slices.

Your code can be simplified by just testing for the key with a membership test:

```
def TestCustom1(Search, Source, Offset=0):
    if Search is None or Search in (
            'Blank', 'Missing IRF - MT', 'Missing IRF - source data',
            'Date out of scope'):
        return 'Blank'

    if Search in Source:
        return TestType('CharZ', Source[Search][Offset:])

    return 'Missing from look up tbl'
```

where `Offset` is assumed to be an integer, defaulting to `0` to slice from the start.

However, note that your function now returns *two different types* based on the match; either a string or a list is returned. Use exceptions instead to communicate exceptional circumstances.

Comment: Martijn - thank you, I will need to tweak your sollution a little bit, but at least I know where to go now :)